# Python compare elements in nested list if larger

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

Got this nested list

```
lst=[['','2018','2018','2015','2015','2012','2012','2009','2009','2006','2006','2003','2003'],
     ['','M','F','M','F','M','F','M','F','M','F','M','F'],
     ['Australia','494','488','497','491','510','498','519','509','527','513','527','522'],
     ['Austria','505','492','510','483','517','494','506','486','517','494','509','502'],
     ['Belgium','514','502','514','500','520','509','526','504','524','517','533','525'],
     ['Japan','532','522','539','525','545','527','534','524','533','513','539','530']]
```

Trying to find for each year if F > M, if so, print

```
Year    Country      Female      Male
2018     Country 3    Score       Score
2015     Country 1     ...        ....
2013     Country 4     ...        ....
2013     Country 5     ...        ....
```

I'm thinking of looking at 2018 first, then 2015 and so on:

```
if lst[2][2]<lst[2][3]:
   print('1')
```

Output from that is 1, so it seems to work.

```
for n in lst[2:]:
  for element in n[1:]:
    print(element)
```

Gives me a list of the scores.
But how do I put this together? "If F>M for 2018 print list, repeat on 2015"?

Comment: You should probably use a dictionary or a JSON file for this type of analysis. Nested lists like this are hard to use.

Comment: You should use dataframes for this, it would be much easier in my opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over `years`, than over `countries`, then getting `male` and `female` values and compare them:

```
lst = [['', '2018', '2018', '2015', '2015', '2012', '2012', '2009', '2009', '2006', '2006', '2003', '2003'],
       ['', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F'],
       ['Australia', '494', '488', '497', '491', '510', '498', '519', '509', '527', '513', '527', '522'],
       ['Austria', '505', '492', '510', '483', '517', '494', '506', '486', '517', '494', '509', '502'],
       ['Belgium', '514', '502', '514', '500', '520', '509', '526', '504', '524', '517', '533', '525'],
       ['Japan', '532', '522', '539', '525', '545', '527', '534', '524', '533', '513', '539', '530']]

print('Year Country Female Male')
for i in range(1, len(lst[0]), 2):
    year = lst[0][i]
    for j in range(2, len(lst)):
        country = lst[j][0]
        m = int(lst[j][i])
        f = int(lst[j][i+1])
        if f > m:
            print(year, country, f, m)
```

There are no countries where `female > male`, so output is empty.

Comment: Many thanks! Did'nt realize that the sample list would be empty, the real list is definetly not empty. Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

Let me introduce You to something like python dictionary.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Your example will be much easier if `dict` where used.

Your list contains this type of info: `years` `country` `male scores` `female scores`.

With dictionaries You could achieve something like this:

```py
lst = {'year': [2018,2018,2015,2015,2012,2012,2009,2009],
       'Australia': [[494,488],[497,491],[510,498],[519,509]] }
```

And acquire `year` and `Australia` by calling:

```py
lst['year'] and lst['Australia']
```

This is more pythonic way of handling this type of data. Also You can see that I've paired [M,F] scores in `Australia`. It's easier to keep track of and iterate over. Let me show You:

```py
for male_and_female_score in lst['Australia']:

    print(male_and_female_score[0]) # this will print a male score
    print(male_and_female_score[1]) # this will print a female score

    # now You can compare
    if male_and_female_score[0] > male_and_female_score[1]:
        print('Male score was higher')
```

Also You need to remember that python index lists from `0`, not `1`.

> Answering You question:
> For simplicity, I will rearrange Your list a little bit.

```py
lst=[['','2018','2018','2015','2015','2012','2012','2009','2009','2006','2006','2003','2003'],
['Australia',['494','488'],['497','491'],['510','498'],['519','509'],['527','513'],['527','522']]]
```

If You will rearrange to something like this, You can:

```py
for elem in lst[2:]:
    print('Country:', elem[0]) # will print "Country: Australia"
    
    for scores in elem[1:]:
        if scores[0] < scores[1] :
            print('Female score:', scores[1])
            print('Male score:', scores[0])
            print('Female score was higher')
```

Additionally, if You want to iterate over two lists at once You can do something like this:

```py
for elem in lst[2:]:
    for score, year in zip(elem[1:],lst[1:]):
        print('Year: ', year, ' Scores:', score)
```

Comment: My compliments on explaining this for me. Are you a teacher? If not, you should be, you have a gift of explaining.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that your sample list contains no instances where the female score is greater than the male score.  I modified the Australia and Japan entries below to prove that the following code works. This solution uses a Pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
lst=[['','2018','2018','2015','2015','2012','2012','2009','2009','2006','2006','2003','2003'],
     ['','M','F','M','F','M','F','M','F','M','F','M','F'],
     ['Australia','494','488','497','491','510','498','519','509','527','513','527','522'],
     ['Austria','505','492','510','512','517','494','506','486','517','494','509','502'],
     ['Belgium','514','502','514','500','520','509','526','504','524','517','533','525'],
     ['Japan','522','532','539','525','545','527','534','524','533','513','539','530']]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
for idx, row in df[2:].iterrows():
        for col in range(2,len(row), 2):
                if int(row[col]) > int(row[col - 1]):
                        print(f'{row[0]}, {df.iloc[0,col]}, female: {row[col]}, male: {row[col-1]}')

#Austria, 2015, female: 512, male: 510
#Japan, 2018, female: 532, male: 522
```

Answer (score 0):

convert it to a dictionary with something like this:
`adjusteddict = {gender:{sex:{country[0]:country[number+1] for country in lst[2:]} for number,sex in enumerate(lst[0][1:]) if gender == lst[1][1:][number]} for gender in ['M','F']}`
will help you tremendously as it organizes the data for you
this results in
`{'M': {'2003': {'Belgium': '533', 'Japan': '539', 'Austria': '509', 'Australia': '527'}, '2006': {'Belgium': '524', 'Japan': '533', 'Austria': '517', 'Australia': '527'}, '2018': {'Belgium': '514', 'Japan': '532', 'Austria': '505', 'Australia': '494'}, '2015': {'Belgium': '514', 'Japan': '539', 'Austria': '510', 'Australia': '497'}, '2009': {'Belgium': '526', 'Japan': '534', 'Austria': '506', 'Australia': '519'}, '2012': {'Belgium': '520', 'Japan': '545', 'Austria': '517', 'Australia': '510'}}, 'F': {'2003': {'Belgium': '525', 'Japan': '530', 'Austria': '502', 'Australia': '522'}, '2006': {'Belgium': '517', 'Japan': '513', 'Austria': '494', 'Australia': '513'}, '2018': {'Belgium': '502', 'Japan': '522', 'Austria': '492', 'Australia': '488'}, '2015': {'Belgium': '500', 'Japan': '525', 'Austria': '483', 'Australia': '491'}, '2009': {'Belgium': '504', 'Japan': '524', 'Austria': '486', 'Australia': '509'}, '2012': {'Belgium': '509', 'Japan': '527', 'Austria': '494', 'Australia': '498'}}}`
which should be your data organized by year and gender (If i am understanding the way you organized your list correctly) in didctionary format you can directly compare data just by comparing the same dictionary index with 'F' instead of 'M'

Answer (score 0):

You could write a few helper function to access your data structure and then use these function to get to the statistics that you are looking for:

```
def getYears(L): return L[0][1::2]

def getYear(year,L):
    y = L[0].index(str(year))-1  # index of year (male column)
    return [ (c,*map(int,N[y:y+2])) for c,*N in L[2:] ] # country & M,F counts

def yearTotals(year,L):
    _,M,F = zip(*getYear(year,L))  # get list of M and F counts
    return sum(M),sum(F)           # return their sum total
```

output:

```
lst=[['','2018','2018','2015','2015','2012','2012','2009','2009','2006','2006','2003','2003'],
     ['','M','F','M','F','M','F','M','F','M','F','M','F'],
     ['Australia','494','488','497','491','510','498','519','509','527','513','527','522'],
     ['Austria','505','492','510','483','517','494','506','486','517','494','509','502'],
     ['Belgium','514','502','514','500','520','509','526','504','524','517','533','525'],
     ['Japan','532','522','539','525','545','527','534','524','533','513','539','530']]

for year in getYears(lst):
    print(year)
    for country,m,f in getYear(year,lst):
        print(f"{country:15} {m:5} {f:5} majority: ","mf"[f>m])
    totM,totF = yearTotals(year,lst)
    print(f"{'TOTALS':15} {totM:5} {totF:5} majority: ","MF"[totF>totM])
    print()

2018
Australia         494   488 majority:  m
Austria           505   492 majority:  m
Belgium           514   502 majority:  m
Japan             532   522 majority:  m
TOTALS           2045  2004 majority:  M

2015
Australia         497   491 majority:  m
Austria           510   483 majority:  m
Belgium           514   500 majority:  m
Japan             539   525 majority:  m
TOTALS           2060  1999 majority:  M

2012
Australia         510   498 majority:  m
Austria           517   494 majority:  m
Belgium           520   509 majority:  m
Japan             545   527 majority:  m
TOTALS           2092  2028 majority:  M

2009
Australia         519   509 majority:  m
Austria           506   486 majority:  m
Belgium           526   504 majority:  m
Japan             534   524 majority:  m
TOTALS           2085  2023 majority:  M

2006
Australia         527   513 majority:  m
Austria           517   494 majority:  m
Belgium           524   517 majority:  m
Japan             533   513 majority:  m
TOTALS           2101  2037 majority:  M

2003
Australia         527   522 majority:  m
Austria           509   502 majority:  m
Belgium           533   525 majority:  m
Japan             539   530 majority:  m
TOTALS           2108  2079 majority:  M
```